# Gmail filters for "-in" not working as expected

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I'm trying to filter my Gmail inbox for all messages that are not a part of a starred conversation.  If I search just for `-in:starred` and start combing through the first few pages of results, everything looks okay.  When I try to combine it with a date filter, I immediately see messages that should not be appearing.  Any ideas why this combination of search filters would be returning invalid results?

[image: Screenshot showing invalid results for my search.]

Comment: Take out the word `AND`. Gmail is searching for it. It is not a boolean operator in Gmail searches.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, the results I'm seeing are identical with and without the (needless) ```AND```.

Comment: Switch off conversation view and see if you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Many times when search is finding conversations that you aren't expecting, the issue is conversation view.

If one message in a conversation meets the criteria, then gmail is going to show you the conversation, even though externally it doesn't seem to match the criteria.

For example: if there are two messages in a conversation but only one message has a star, then the GUI will show a star next to the conversation. However a search for is:starred  will find the conversation and another search for -is:starred  will also find the conversation.

If you temporarily turn off conversation view the results should match what you expect.